# comparison of integer and floating point numbers in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In shell script how can we compare (integer and floating point) ,(flaoting point and floating point),(floating point and integer),(integer and integer) with only one if condition.

i have  few examples like

```
 set X=3.1
  set Y=4.1
  if [ $X < $Y ] then
    echo "wassup"
  endif
```

But running the above from cron job doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: Integer expression expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958855/bash-integer-expression-expected)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The way to carry out floating point operations in bash is to use [bc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html) which is available on almost all linux distributions.

```
# bc will return 0 for false and 1 for true
if [ $(echo "23.3 > 7.3" | bc) -ne 0 ] 
then 
  echo "wassup"
fi
```

There's a [good article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/floating-point-math-bash) available on linux journal about floating point math in bash using bc.

Comment: i tried the following and got a error as unary operated expected

Comment: interesting. I have it working fine here. Hmmm. What your error means (I think) is that the `$(echo "$a > $b" | bc)` did not return a value. Can you try the subshell on its own?

Comment: IE: Your variables are not properly assigned to. `echo $X` will be an empty line, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Bah itself only handles integers. Use bc:

```
echo "$X>$Y" | bc 
0
echo "$X<$Y" | bc 
1
```

You don't need to worry about scale. It is just for the preocision of output formats:

```
X=3.000001
Y=3.0001
echo "$X>$Y" | bc 
0
echo "$X<$Y" | bc 
1
echo "scale=1;$X<$Y" | bc 
1
```

Answer (score 0):

below example works on bash shell.

```
 X=3.1
 Y=4.1
 if [ $X -le $Y ]
 then
    echo "wassup"
 fi
```

you may want to learn shell script [here](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/)

Comment: This doesn't work here, as bash doesn't deal with floating points: `$ test "34.4" -gt "5.4" -> 
bash: test: 34.4: integer expression expected`

Comment: I do not doubt your sincerity :) I'm just saying that this isn't guaranteed to work on Linux `bash --version` gives me `GNU bash, version 4.2.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT. based on the comments to this answer (thanks to *user unknown* and *glenn jackman*), it seems that when using `bc` for a *true/false* test, the required `bash` test is simply:

- `(( $(echo "$X < $Y" |bc) ))` ... see the test results and script below

wheras, the comparison to `-ne 0` is needed for the old style bash `[   ]` test.

---

`bash` does not natively handle floating point numbers, but you can call a utility such as `bc`

From `man bc` *- An arbitrary precision calculator language*

```
X=3.1
Y=4.1
# This test has two superfluous components. 
# See EDIT (above) and TESTS below
if (($(echo "scale=9; $X < $Y" |bc)!=0)) ;then
    echo "wassup"
fi
```

---

TEST results:

```
if [  "1"  ]   true
   [  "1"  ]   true
if [  "0"  ]   true
   [  "0"  ]   true

if [   1   ]   true
   [   1   ]   true
if [   0   ]   true
   [   0   ]   true

if (( "1" ))   true
   (( "1" ))   true
if (( "0" ))   false
   (( "0" ))   false

if ((  1  ))   true
   ((  1  ))   true
if ((  0  ))   false
   ((  0  ))   false

echo "1<1"|bc  true
echo "1<0"|bc  true
```

---

TEST script:

```
printf 'if [  "1"  ]   '; if [ "1" ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
printf '   [  "1"  ]   ';    [ "1" ]  &&   echo true  ||   echo false
printf 'if [  "0"  ]   '; if [ "0" ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
printf '   [  "0"  ]   ';    [ "0" ]  &&   echo true  ||   echo false
echo  
printf 'if [   1   ]   '; if [  1  ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
printf '   [   1   ]   ';    [  1  ]  &&   echo true  ||   echo false
printf 'if [   0   ]   '; if [  0  ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
printf '   [   0   ]   ';    [  0  ]  &&   echo true  ||   echo false
echo  
printf 'if (( "1" ))   '; if (("1")); then echo true; else echo false; fi
printf '   (( "1" ))   ';    (("1"))  &&   echo true  ||   echo false
printf 'if (( "0" ))   '; if (("0")); then echo true; else echo false; fi
printf '   (( "0" ))   ';    (("0"))  &&   echo true  ||   echo false
echo  
printf 'if ((  1  ))   '; if (( 1 )); then echo true; else echo false; fi
printf '   ((  1  ))   ';    (( 1 ))  &&   echo true  ||   echo false
printf 'if ((  0  ))   '; if (( 0 )); then echo true; else echo false; fi
printf '   ((  0  ))   ';    (( 0 ))  &&   echo true  ||   echo false
echo
printf 'echo "1<1"|bc  '; echo "1<1"|bc >/dev/null  && echo true || echo false 
printf 'echo "1<0"|bc  '; echo "1<0"|bc >/dev/null  && echo true || echo false
```

Comment: `scale` is superfluous, if you just want to test for true and false. `!=0` is superfluous too - that's what's done already.

Comment: The `!=0` is *not* superfluous: bc *prints* 0 or 1 for false or true. In both cases, the *exit status* is zero. So, you must compare the command output to something.

Comment: Nice idea, but wrong: `if (($(echo "$X > $Y" | bc))) ; then echo wassup; else echo pussaw; fi`. Reason: $(...) captures the output. ((...)) evaluates.

Comment: It seems you are both right, *for different formats* :) ... I've added tests to my answer.

Comment: @glennjackman: I forgot the notification mark for you. Sorry.