# Bash: Integer expression expected

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm trying to perform simple math, to check if a variable is greater or equal to "1.5"
but I'm getting `[: 2.41: integer expression expected`

Code:

```
reSum=$(expr "scale=1;555/230" | bc)

if [ $reSum -ge "1.5" ]; then
...
fi
```

How can I do floating-point comparisons in shell script?

Comment: From `info expr` `< <= = == != >= >'
     Compare the arguments and return 1 if the relation is true, 0
     otherwise.  `==' is a synonym for `='.  `expr' first tries to
     convert both arguments to integers and do a numeric comparison; if
     either conversion fails, it does a lexicographic comparison using
     the character collating sequence specified by the `LC_COLLATE'
     locale.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if echo 555 230 | awk '{exit $1/$2 >= 1.5 ? 0 : 1}'
then
  # ...
fi
```

Comment: no external packages needed with this!

Answer (score 2):

*Edit:*

The shortest solution that works for me:

```
reSum=$(expr "scale=1;555/230" | bc)

if (( `echo $reSum'>='1.5 | bc` )); then
  # anything
fi
```

As pointed out by shellter, `[ $(expr "$reSum > 1.5" | bc) ]` actually does a lexicographic comparison.
So, for example, `expr "2.4 > 18 | bc" // =>0`.

However, `` (( `echo $reSum'>='1.5 | bc` )) `` does floating point comparison rather than strings.