# Weird Bash error while comparing a string and a variable

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

So I am pretty familiar with bash but the second if statement keeps throwing me an error.

```
./run.sh: line 39: [: q: integer expression expected
./run.sh: line 39: [: q: integer expression expected
```

I am not exactly sure what is the problem. I am pretty sure my syntax is correct.

```
read -p "Option Number-> " answer
#  Check to see if the answer is only letters
if [[ "$answer" =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+$ ]];then
    if [ "$answer" -eq "q" ] || [ "$answer" -eq "Q" ];then
        exit
    fi
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: [How can I compare a variable to a text string, rather than integer, in an if/else statement?](https://superuser.com/q/543793/173513), [Bash - Integer expression expected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/293495/56041), [Bash: Integer expression expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17958855/608639), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-eq` is used for integer comparisons, for text comparisons use `=`

From the `bash` `man` pages:

> arg1 OP arg2
>
> ```
>           OP  is one of -eq, -ne, -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.  These arithmetic
>           binary operators return true if arg1 is equal to, not equal  to,
>           less  than, less than or equal to, greater than, or greater than
>           or equal to arg2, respectively.  Arg1 and arg2 may  be  positive
>           or negative integers.
> ```

and

> string1 == string2
>
> string1 = string2
>
> ```
>           True if the strings are equal.  = should be used with  the  test
>           command  for  POSIX conformance.  When used with the [[ command,
>           this performs pattern matching as described above (Compound Com-
>           mands).
> ```

By the way, your comparison could be written as a *pattern*:

```
if [[ "$answer" == [Qq] ]]
```

Comment: There must be dozens of duplicates for this. Although I'm not sure how to search for them.

Comment: @Barmar:  probably, but it's quicker to answer it.

Comment: Well, this is a nice, succinct answer, I'll make it my dupe candidate.

Comment: @Barmar I only found lots of questions with that error message that are *almost* duplicates, but no good one.

Comment: However, I don't think "quicker to answer" is a good reason to answer duplicates.

Comment: You're the best

Comment: And yes trust me I am not trying to create duplicates. I know it was a stupid syntax error but I was stuck on it for an hour and bash errors are so vague that nothing helpful comes up on google.

Comment: @jjones:  sympathies.  The problem with searching for duplicates is that you often need to know the answer to do the right search!