# need shell script to sort numbers including decimal numbers

Tags: shell

shell script to sort numbers including decimal numbers

I tried the following script and list with decimal number not working.

```
arr=(10 8 -20 100 1.2)

echo "Array in original order" echo ${arr[*]}

for ((i = 0; i<5; i++)) do

for((j = 0; j<5-i-1; j++)) 
do

    if [ ${arr[j]} -gt ${arr[$((j+1))]} ] 
    then
         
        temp=${arr[j]} 
        arr[$j]=${arr[$((j+1))]} 
        arr[$((j+1))]=$temp 
    fi
done
done
echo "Array in sorted order :" echo ${arr[*]}
```

OUTPUT:

Array in original order 10 8 -20 100 1.2 ./sort.sh: line 17: [: 1.2: integer expression expected Array in sorted order : -20 8 10 100 1.2

i want the list to be as follow:

-20 1.2 8 10 100

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66049811/shell-script-to-sort-numbers-including-decimal-numbers)?

Comment: please see this thread which has the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939546/comparison-of-integer-and-floating-point-numbers-in-shell-script

Comment: @anadanramar : Please specify ths shell you are using. You tag it as shell, which would mean POSIX shell, but it is certainly **not** POSIX shell, because you are using an Array, and POSIX shell does not have arrays. BTW: If you want to sort floats, I suggest to use Zsh, which can do float arithmetic.

Comment: @user1934428, it can do float arithmetic, but it has no knowledge on how to do numeric sorting of arrays. If you are referring to `"${(@n)array}"` then this does not behave as you expect.

Comment: Is this a homework question to implement a sorting algorithm, or are external binaries allowed (such as `sort`)

Comment: @kvantour : Maybe we have some misunderstanding here, but for all that I know, POSIX shell neither has arrays nor floating point arithmetic. If you have different information, I would appreciate if you can provide me some link on that matter.

Comment: @user1934428 I was referring to zsh. While zsh has knowledge of floating-point arithmetic, zsh cannot sort an array numerically when it contains floats. Only when it contains positive integers.

Comment: @kvantour : Zsh, like bash, does **not** have any sorting algorithm built in. You have to write your own. Of course you **can** use an external program, such as `sort`, for this purpose but then you are stuck to what this offers. This is **unrelated** to the shell itself. Since writing a sort program  is no rocket science, I suggest you just implement your own sort-function, and then can provide any additional whistles and bells you need for it.

Comment: @user1934428 ZSH does have knowledge of sorting. Have a look at the glob-qualifiers `o` and `O` to sort arrays.

Comment: @kvantour : Right, I forgot this. And I now believe to see the bug in the sorting code of the OP: He is doing a `if [ ${arr[j]} -gt ${arr[$((j+1))]} ]` to compare the numbers. The correct way would be `if (( arr[j] > arr[j+1] ))`, which would work with floats as well. IMO, the question should be reopened because of this.

Comment: @kvantour : I now remember that the OP required POSIX shell, so I see that my zsh solution does not make sense for him anyway. Therefore, reopening of course is not advisable.

Answer (score 1):

> i want the list to be as follow: -20 1.2 8 10 100

1. Output numbers one per line.
2. Sort
3. Join with space

```
$ arr=(10 8 -20 100 1.2)
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | sort -g | paste -sd' '
-20 1.2 8 10 100
```

Don't reimplement `sort` using shell - it's going to be incredibly slow. The `-g` option to `sort` may not be available everywhere - it's for sorting floating point numbers.

> [: 1.2: integer expression expected Array

The `[` command handles integers only. `1.2` has a comma, `[` can't handle it. Use another tool. Preferable `python`.

> ```
> ${arr[$((j+1))]}
> ```

No need to use `$((` - stuff inside `[` is already expanded arithmetically. Just `${arr[j+1]}`.

> ```
> j<5-i-1
> ```

is strange condition. When `i=4` then it's `j<0` and loop will not run at all. Just iterate *from* `i` instead of *up to* i - `((j=i;j<5;++j))`.

> ```
> echo "Array in sorted order :" echo ${arr[*]}
> ```

Will print `echo` to output. Just `echo "Array in sorted order : ${arr[*]}"` or `echo "Array in sorted order :" "${arr[@]}"`